# return undefined on fetch request inside map react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to get a map array from fetch resolves so on every element inside favoriteCards it returns a value and assigns it in test

```
useEffect(() => {
  const test = favoriteCards.map((card) => {
    accuWeatherApi.getCurrentWeather(card.key).then((res) => {
      return res;
    });
  });
  setRenderFavorites(test);
}, [favoriteCards]);

console.log(renderFavorites)
```

I always get undefined no matter what I do

Comment: try console logging `card` inside `map` and then try console logging `res`

Comment: @DharmikPatel all logging perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getCurrentWeather` operation is *asynchronous*.  So in this case you need to `await` a series of operations to get their results *before* you can set those results to a state value.

In a `useEffect` that might look something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchWeather = async () => {
    // begin the asynchronous operations
    const promises = favoriteCards.map(card => accuWeatherApi.getCurrentWeather(card.key));

    // wait for all of them to complete
    const results = await Promise.all(promises);

    // update state with the results
    setRenderFavorites(results);
  }

  fetchWeather();
}, [favoriteCards]);
```

Though as you might imagine, there are a variety of ways to do this.  For example, the above code performs all of the asynchronous operations right away and the results will be in whatever order they finish.  If you need them to be in the same order, you might `await` each operation one at a time.  For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchWeather = async () => {
    const results = [];

    // await each operations in order
    for (const card of favoriteCards) {
      results.push(await accuWeatherApi.getCurrentWeather(card.key));
    }

    // update state with the results
    setRenderFavorites(results);
  }

  fetchWeather();
}, [favoriteCards]);
```

Note that in each case the function passed to `useEffect` itself is *not* `async`.  But since asynchronous operations need to be awaited, internally that function defines a function which *is* `async` and then invokes that function.  Internal to *that* function is where you'd `await` the operations.

---

As an aside, it's also worth pointing out that there was a *second* issue in your code... The syntax of your use of `.map()` explicitly doesn't return anything.  When curly braces are used in the function passed to `.map()` then there is no default return and you need to explicitly `return` a value.  So even if you were awaiting the operations or if they weren't asynchronous in the first place, it would still be `undefined` because there's no return value.